# Can a character intentionally fail their save against shadow conjuration?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can a character intentionally fail their save to disbelieve against a Shadow Conjuration spell that is mimicking a summoning spell to gain the full benefit of any healing that a summoned creature might grant, even if they are fully aware that the creature summoned is an illusion?

Comment: Not sure how a question can be an exact duplicate despite involving a different spell but okay.